# c# datagridview row indeces validation

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

If I double click a row header cell of my gridview, I get an index parameter error.  I tried fixing that in my Double click event with my RowIndex statement, but is there another place I'm supposed to do this?

```
private void DGV1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {


                try
                {
                     if ((e.ColumnIndex > 0))
                    {
                        EditUser eu = new EditUser();
                        eu.UserId = DGV1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                        FormFunctions.OpenMdiDataForm(Program.GetMainMdiParent(), eu);    
                    }
                    if (e.RowIndex == 0 || e.RowIndex == -1)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error\n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
```

Comment: -1 is a valid index that the `DataGridView` will use to indicate actions in the RowHeader or ColumnHeader. This is defined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Your validation logic is not applied in the desired order. Change your check condition to something like this:

```
try
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex > 0 && e.RowIndex > 0)
    {
        EditUser eu = new EditUser();
        eu.UserId = DGV1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        FormFunctions.OpenMdiDataForm(Program.GetMainMdiParent(), eu);    
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error\n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```